# Удаление данных из деструктора

Tags: c++

Сорри, если глупый вопрос, я только учу с++

Есть такой класс:

```
class GC
{
public:
    GC()
    {
        static int** gcm = new int[];
    }

    int** cnew()
    {
        static int* ptr = new int;
        static int** tptr = &ptr;
        return tptr;
    }

    ~GC()
    {
        delete[] gcm;
    }
};
```

Microsoft Visual C++ говорит, что `identiifier "gcm" is undefined`.

`Static` не помогает.

Это только каркас. Как в деструкторе удалить массив?

Comment: Предвосхищая ваш следующий вопрос - а что вы хотели получить здесь - `int** gcm = new int[];`? Просто указатели на указатели - конструкция не слишком удобная...

Comment: Код не полный, наброски. Тренируюсь, пишу простую реализацию garbage collector. Just for fun.

Comment: Я не эксперт, но написание Garbage collector для языка, в котором Вы не знаете, как работать с памятью, считаю гиблой затеей. Советую для начала изучить основы, потом умные указатели, а потом уже подумать "а зачем мне GC?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы объявляете переменную в теле конструктора. Конечно, в деструкторе её не видно, она остаётся там, где была объявлена. А значит, надо объявлять её в самом классе:

```
class GC {
private:
    int* gcm;

public:

    GC() {
        gcm = new int[??];
    }

    int** cnew() {
        // не надо использовать static в теле метода!
        int* ptr = new int;
        int** tptr = &ptr;
        return tptr;
    }

    ~GC() {
        delete[] gcm;
    }

};
```

---

Модификатор `static` перед объявлением переменной класса делает эту переменную *статической*, то есть, общей для всех экземпляров класса. Такие переменные также нужно объявлять в самом классе, а не в теле конструктора, деструктора или другого метода.

Comment: Сделал как Вы указали. Ошибка "value of int* cannot be assigned to an entity of type of int**".

Comment: Ваш вопрос был на счёт области видимости переменной и её модификатора, а тип переменной - уже другое дело. Я обратил внимание на неверное количество звёздочек, но исправление этой ошибки зависит уже от Вашей задачи. Можно исправить указатель, как я сейчас сделал в коде, а можно выделять память на массив массивов - Ваше право.

Comment: Извиняюсь, но я запутался. Подскажите рабочий пример.

Comment: @j0hn `int** gcm;` - стоит убрать одну звёздочку, код будет работать. Потому, что `new int[];` возвращает указатель на int = `int*`. А Вы изначально объявляли указатель на указатель.

Comment: Не работает. gsm=new int[]; -> array size must be specified in new expressions

Comment: Надо просто указать размер выделяемой памяти.